# How to use trpc and react-query within a function for useMutation()

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, server, react-query, trpc

I have a very specific problem. I have been using trpc with react-query and so far it has been amazing and this is the only big issue I've faced with it. Following the setup for trpc/react-query/next.js 14 I have a simple server for todos which is as follows:

```
// utils
import sleep from "@/lib/utils/sleep";
import { router, privateProcedure } from "../trpc";
import { z } from "zod";

type Todo = {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
};

const todos: Todo[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "todo 1",
    completed: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "todo 2",
    completed: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "todo 3",
    completed: false,
  },
];

const todoRouter = router({
  getTodos: privateProcedure.query(async ({ ctx }) => {
    await sleep(1000);

    return todos;
  }),

  addTodo: privateProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        text: z.string(),
      })
    )
    .mutation(async ({ input }) => {
      await sleep(1000);

      const todo: Todo = {
        id: todos.length + 1,
        text: input.text,
        completed: false,
      };

      todos.push(todo);

      return todo;
    }),

  updateTodo: privateProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        id: z.number(),
        text: z.string(),
        completed: z.boolean(),
      })
    )
    .mutation(async ({ input }) => {
      await sleep(1000);

      const todo = todos.find((todo) => todo.id === input.id);

      if (!todo) {
        throw new Error("Todo not found");
      }

      todo.text = input.text;
      todo.completed = input.completed;

      return todo;
    }),

  deleteTodo: privateProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        id: z.number(),
      })
    )
    .mutation(async ({ input }) => {
      await sleep(1000);

      const index = todos.findIndex((todo) => todo.id === input.id);

      if (index === -1) {
        throw new Error("Todo not found");
      }

      todos.splice(index, 1);

      return true;
    }),
});

export default todoRouter;
```

I want to use the mutation **UpdateTodos** within another function, which is housed with a zustand store. The main issue is this, usually you invoke trpc like so:

```
const mutation = trpc.todo.updateTodo.useMutation();

const handleChecked = async (e) => {
 await sleep(1000);

 const updatedTodo = await mutation.mutateAsync({
  // input fields here
 });

 console.log(updatedTodo);
}
```

My problem is that I am trying to call updateTodo from trpc within a zustand store, so I can't invoke trpc useMutation() as it's within the setup of my zustand store which breaks the rules of hooks. The only way (I know and can think of) to access the updateTodo mutation is by invoking it as above. Does anybody know how I can do it otherwise? A visual representation of the issue is below:

```
const store = create((set, get)=>({
 // state
 todos:[],

 // actions
 addTodo:() => {},
 ...
 updateTodo: async({input}) => {
  // do some stuff

  const mutation = trpc.todo.updateTodo.useMutation();

  await sleep(1000);

  const updatedTodo = mutation.mutateAsync({
   // inputs
  }) 

  console.log(updatedTodo);
 }

}))
```

The above example is simplified to explain my situation as I know that the setup is redundant but for my specific use case it's required and a lot more detailed. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have spent a long time trying to solve this.

As mentioned above in the questions explanation.